# How to recognise TapGesture on overlay view in ImagePickerController() ?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to add UITapGestureRecogniser to the overlay view that I have created for the UIImagePickerController. However no taps are being detected. Following is my code :

```
 //Setting up image picker controller
 let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
 imagePicker.delegate = self
 imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
 imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false

 //Setting up the tap gesture
 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cropImageAroundTap(sender:)))
 tapGesture.delegate = self

 //Setting up overlay view
 let overlayView = UIView.init(frame: self.view.frame)
 overlayView.isOpaque = false
 overlayView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
 overlayView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

 imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
 self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil )
```

If I add the gesture recogniser to the imagePicker.view then the part where the camera controls were detects the taps but not the preview window. Following is my function for detecting taps :

```
func cropImageAroundTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

     if sender.state == .ended {

       NSLog("hello")
     }

}
```

Is there a way to detect taps on the preview window?

Comment: try to use sender.view

Comment: The issue is the selector  cropImageAroundTap is not even being called.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to detect tap gestures in the preview view of the image picker when instead of setting :

```
 imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
```

I added the overlayView as a subview of the imagePicker

```
 imagePicker.view.addSubview(overlayView)
```